# Key matching based on an array containing the pattern

Tags: php

I have 2 array, one contains a formula for this 2 array.

```php
$A =  array(
    '/posrednik/wynagrodzenie/kwartalne/1102019Q4' => array(),
    '/posrednik/wynagrodzenie/kwartalne/1102018Q4' => array(),
    '/posrednik/wynagrodzenie/kwartalne/1202018Q4' => array(),
    '/posrednik/wynagrodzenie/kwartalne/user/test123'  => array(),
    '/posrednik/posrednicy/92/osoby' => array()
);

$B =    array (
    '/posrednik/wynagrodzenie/kwartalne/{quarterly:id}' => array(),
    '/posrednik/wynagrodzenie/kwartalne/user/{list_userVariables}' => array(),
    '/posrednik/konsorcja/{consortium:id}/attach' => array(),
    '/bgk/kontrole-u-pf/{control:id}/pracownicy/{person:id}' => array(),
    '/posrednik/posrednicy/{intermediary:id}/osoby' => array()
);
```

I would like to get the effect:

```php
$C =  array (
    '/posrednik/wynagrodzenie/kwartalne/{quarterly:id}' => array(),
    '/posrednik/wynagrodzenie/kwartalne/user/{list_userVariables}' => array(),
    '/posrednik/posrednicy/{intermediary:id}/osoby' => array()
);
```

I would like to match the keys from the table A to B, With the values ​​in Table A

Comment: You might want to check the usage of quotes `'` and commas `,` in your arrays, that looks odd. Also maybe try to explain in a little more detail what you're trying to achieve, I personally have no clue what "_the effect_" is you're after

Comment: I agree with @kerbh0lz. No idea what you are trying to do, even after cleaning up invalid code. You C array has none of the keys from the A array and is missing two items from the B array. What are the bracketed things, do they mean something? Is this Polish? Do those words mean something that would help us (this SO is English) or are they arbitrary and not related to the problem?